# PowerBI make X axis dynamic

Tags: charts, powerbi, data-visualization

I have a table in Power BI that looks like this -

| Id | Fruit | Color | Taste | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Red | Sweet | 10 |
| 2 | Apple | Green | Sour | 5 |
| 3 | Orange | Orange | Sweet | 20 |
| 4 | Grape | Violet | Sweet | 10 |
| 5 | Banana | Yellow | Sweet | 5 |
| 6 | Grape | Green | Sweet | 20 |

Like Fruits, Color and Taste, I have close to 50 columns, and I want to create a bar chart that dynamically changes X axis (on click of the column name as per user choice) and plots the sum of price as Y value. I tried to achieve this by creating a second table that has all the column names and its attribute combination (like a helper table with 2 columns), but the view created by that method is not working with the slicers present. (e.g. bar chart for X axis= Fruit, filtered for color = Red).

Is there a way to get this done?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Use the new field parameter functionality that was released in May. You can see instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-field-parameters